Differentiating a constant using the chain rule
My students asked a simple question that I wasn't sure about.  Let's say you have $f(x) = csc(e^2)$ and you differentiate with respect to $x$.  The derivative is obviously $0$ because the function is constant.  But can you consider the function as a composition of functions and differentiate it as such, i.e. $$f'(x) = (-csc(e^2)cot(e^2))(2e)(0)$$
I'm thinking this is not correct because you can't differentiate with respect to constants based on the limit definition of a derivative, but I want to be sure.  Any insight / confirmation / critique would be appreciated!

This is fine. You can do this with any constant with silly manipulations, e.g. $$\frac{d}{dx}(5) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{25-1087\sin(5\pi)}\right) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{25-1087\sin(5\pi)}}\cdot\left(2\cdot5-1087\pi\cos(5\pi)\right)\cdot 0$$

You don't have to write the derivative explicitly if you know that the function is differentiable. You can write $\frac{df(c(x))}{dx}=f'(c(x))c'(x)=f'(c(x))\cdot 0=0$. Note that I write $c(x)$ for the constant because you cannot take the derivative of a number; the derivative can only be applied to a function.

What you've described does still work. The chain rule works with a composition of functions: here, you're setting $f(x) = g(h(p(x)))$, with $g(x) = \csc(x)$, $h(x)=x^2$, and $p(x) =e$. Applying the chain rule gives us
$$
f'(x) = g'(h(p(x))) \cdot h'(p(x)) \cdot p'(x),
$$
which gives exactly what you described.

I understand that the computation works but it just feels unsettling to take a derivative with respect to a constant because that would imply that I'm taking a limit as a constant approaches itself

@analysischallenged: It's not clear to me what it even means to "take a derivative with respect to a constant". Here, $f$ is a function, and we can compute its derivative $f'$. There is no such thing as the derivative of $f$ "with respect to" a variable -- that phrase is typically only used when someone asks something like "what is the derivative of $x+t^2$", and it's unclear whether the function we are dealing with is $x\mapsto x+t^2$ or $t\mapsto x+t^2$ (or perhaps the function $(x,t)\mapsto x+t^2$ if we were doing multivariable calculus).

Oh wait!  I see what you're saying now!  Okay!

@Sambo You cannot take the derivative of a constant value. That is the point. You can take the derivative of a constant function but an expression like $\frac{d(2)}{dx}$ makes no sense.

@JohnDouma: I agree with your first sentence but not your last one. The Leibnizian notation for the derivative is not entirely precise anyway, but I think most mathematicians would read $\frac{d(2)}{dx}$ as denoting the derivative of the function $t\mapsto 2$ at the number $x$. (Perhaps you meant to write $\frac{dx}{d2}$ as an example of meaningless notation...)

@JohnDouma How does what you're saying have anything to do with what I wrote?

@Sambo I was addressing your response to the first comment by analysischallenged. He worded it as "respect to a constant" but his sentiment was that you cannot take the derivative of a constant.

@Joe The symbol "2" represents a number, not a function. That notation is incorrect.

@JohnDouma: People write things like $\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ all the time; do you object to that notation too? After all, you could say that $x^2$ is a number and not a function. The point is that the symbol on the bottom of $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ binds the variable $x$; so we are not taking the derivative of "$f(x)$" literally, but rather taking the derivative of $x\mapsto f(x)$.

And, as I wrote above, I agree that people use Leibnizian notation in inconsistent or logically imprecise ways; I'm just claiming that as an empirical fact, mathematicians would understand $\frac{d(2)}{dx}$ in the way I stated above.

@Joe No, mathematicians don't. Engineers and students will use notation like that, but a mathematician will not.

@JohnDouma: That exact notation $\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ literally appears on the chapter on derivatives of Spivak's Calculus, one of the most famous and standard textbooks used in undergraduate courses on analysis. Aside from that, I've seen plenty of mathematicians use it myself.

@Joe Does $\frac{d(2)}{dx}$ appear? I am not talking about taking $\frac{d}{dx}$ of a function. If you want to use the symbol "2" to mean a function, you must state that explicitly. That was my point. The chain rule only applies to the composition of functions. Expressions like $\frac{d(2)}{dx}$ or $\frac{d\pi}{dx}$ don't make any sense.

@JohnDouma: Actually, yes, it does appear; at least, it appears as $\frac{dc}{dx}=0$ on page 155 of the fourth edition. Here, $c$ denotes a number, not a function; this is clear from the previous pages of the text. And if you think $\frac{dx^2}{dx}$ is acceptable notation, then so is $\frac{d2}{dx}$; in both cases, the "numerator" denotes an expression which is bound by the variable $x$ on the "denominator". This is exactly analogous to the notation $x\mapsto x^2$ for functions, which is also very common.

@Joe If Spivak is saying that the derivative of a number is zero, then he is wrong.

@JohnDouma: No, he is not claiming that. He is claiming that if $c\in\mathbb R$ then the derivative of the function $x\mapsto c$ is the zero function. Yes, $c$ on its own is a number. But the "$x^2$" in $x\mapsto x^2$ is also a number, even though "$x\mapsto x^2$" denotes a function. The situation with the Leibnizian notation is pretty much the same.

There is a problem with your derivative and this should be stated clearly to your students. You cannot take the derivative of a number. You can only take the derivative of a function.
For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, I cannot use the chain rule to compute $f'(2)$. I can use the chain rule to compute the derivative of $f(c(x))$ where $c(x)=2$ for all $x$.

This is what I'm thinking: there really is no composition of functions here because the entire function is simply a constant that happens to be obtained through application of functions to a constant.

@analysischallenged The point is that there is a difference between a constant $c$ and a function that takes the value of $c$ for all $x$. To teach otherwise is to be irresponsible and incompetent.

This answer is irrelevant and unhelpful. Nowhere in the question does it talk about using the chain rule to compute something like $f'(2)$. Moreover, any calculus teacher will say "take the derivative of a constant" to mean "take the derivative of a constant function", so while understanding this subtlety is arguably important, scorning people who say the first phrase is simply ludicrous.

@Sambo This answer is entirely relevant. Look at the last paragraph of the question. Analysischallenged specifically mentions the problem correctly. You cannot assume that the number $2$ is the function that maps $x$ to $2$. Using the chain rule in this manner is incorrect. Not only is this answer relevant, it should be the accepted answer.
